# How to read contents of a csv file inside zip file using PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell, zip, archive

I have a zip file which contains several CSV files inside it. How do I read the contents of those CSV files without extracting the zip files using PowerShell?

I having been using the `Read-Archive` Cmdlet which is included as part of the [PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX)](https://pscx.codeplex.com/)

This is what I have tried so far.

```
$path = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\"
$fullpath = Join-Path $path filename.zip

Read-Archive $fullpath | Foreach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.Name
}
```

But when I run the code, I get this error message
**Get-Content : An object at the specified path filename.csv does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.**

However, when I run `Read-Archive $fullpath`, it lists all the file inside the zip file

Answer (score 23):

There are multiple ways of achieving this:

**1. Here's an example using Ionic.zip dll:**

```
clear
Add-Type -Path "E:\sw\NuGet\Packages\DotNetZip.1.9.7\lib\net20\Ionic.Zip.dll"
$zip = [Ionic.Zip.ZipFile]::Read("E:\E.zip")

$file = $zip | where-object { $_.FileName -eq "XMLSchema1.xsd"}

$stream = new-object IO.MemoryStream
$file.Extract($stream)
$stream.Position = 0

$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$text = $reader.ReadToEnd()
$text

$reader.Close()
$stream.Close()
$zip.Dispose()
```

It's picking the file by name (XMLSchema1.xsd) and extracting it into the memory stream. You then need to read the memory stream into something that you like (string in my example).

**2. In Powershell 5, you could use `Expand-Archive`**, see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It would extract entire archive into a folder:

```
Expand-Archive "E:\E.zip" "e:\t"
```

Keep in mind that extracting entire archive is taking time and you will then have to cleanup the temporary files

**3. And one more way to extract just 1 file:**

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace("E:\E.zip")
$file =  $zip.items() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "XMLSchema1.xsd"}
$shell.Namespace("E:\t").copyhere($file)
```

**4. And one more way using native means:**

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
$zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead("e:\E.zip")
$file = $zip.Entries | where-object { $_.Name -eq "XMLSchema1.xsd"}
$stream = $file.Open()

$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$text = $reader.ReadToEnd()
$text

$reader.Close()
$stream.Close()
$zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: This requires having third party dll installed. Would prefer without one.

Comment: True, but still you are using extensions, which are a bit more difficult to install that just a dll

Comment: I would like a solution which does not require extracting the zip. Also updated my question to mention that.

Comment: Your update still requires extracting all the files inside the zip file to a folder

Comment: Getting **You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.** for `$stream = $file.Open()`

Comment: Did you change the file name?

Comment: No. It did not change it.

Comment: The code is working for me, so check what files you have inside archive (see what's inside `$zip.Entries`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113487/discussion-between-ishan-and-andrey-marchuk).

Comment: For the powershell solution 5th one, i am getting error if zip file name and file inside zip is bot matching. How do we over come this issue? Any thoughts

Answer (score 8):

Based on 4. solution of Andrey, I propose the following function:

*(keep in mind that "ZipFile" class exists starting at .NET Framework 4.5)*

```
Add-Type -assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

function Read-FileInZip($ZipFilePath, $FilePathInZip) {
    try {
        if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($ZipFilePath)) {
            throw "Zip file ""$ZipFilePath"" not found."
        }

        $Zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($ZipFilePath)
        $ZipEntries = [array]($Zip.Entries | where-object {
                return $_.FullName -eq $FilePathInZip
            });
        if (!$ZipEntries -or $ZipEntries.Length -lt 1) {
            throw "File ""$FilePathInZip"" couldn't be found in zip ""$ZipFilePath""."
        }
        if (!$ZipEntries -or $ZipEntries.Length -gt 1) {
            throw "More than one file ""$FilePathInZip"" found in zip ""$ZipFilePath""."
        }

        $ZipStream = $ZipEntries[0].Open()

        $Reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($ZipStream)
        return $Reader.ReadToEnd()
    }
    finally {
        if ($Reader) { $Reader.Dispose() }
        if ($Zip) { $Zip.Dispose() }
    }
}
```