# How to confirm the files I unzipped from the folder are correct

Tags: powershell

In my powershell script I'm unzipping a "filename.zip" file, once done I want to cross check if the number of files I unzipped and placed in a folder is equal to the number of files in the "filename.zip". Is there any way to do that? Because sometimes few files are being missed out.

Note: I'm using powershell version 2.0

```
$zip_file="D:\speter071714\OMS.DODU.Qa.$version_no.zip"
$DODU_folder="D:\speter071714\DODU\"
echo "Extracting the DODU.zip file"
$shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$zip1=$shell.NameSpace("$zip_file")
foreach ($item1 in $zip1.items())
{
$shell.Namespace("$DODU_folder").CopyHere($item1)
}
```

I basically want to compare the content in `$zip_file="D:\speter071714\OMS.DODU.Qa.$version_no.zip"`
and `$DODU_folder="D:\speter071714\DODU\"`

Answer (score 0):

If a few files are missing it means that your unzipping method is not very good. See here if any other method for you is better: [How to read contents of a csv file inside zip file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561465/how-to-read-contents-of-a-csv-file-inside-zip-file-using-powershell/37561878#37561878)

But regarding your way, you already have all the items inside zip file in `$zip1.items()`, so you could check `Name` property of each of the items and then see if the file exists in the output folder.