# Read Text-File inside ZIP in Powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I want to read text files that are stored inside a ZIP-File.
Currently I extract the desired files using 7Zip, read them and delete them again.
Is there a way to read them without extracting them onto the hard drive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### tl;dr

**Yes, there is a way.** but is there a nice way? **No, definitely not.**

---

There is a way. But this heavily depends on your operating system. PowerShell 5 has [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1), which makes using 7Zip obsolete, but even with [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1) you'd have to extract the whole archive to read your file's contents.

Using a windows machine, you could accomplish it with the `shell.application` Com Object or [`system.io.compression.filesystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) like quoted from this thread:
[How to read contents of a csv file inside zip file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561878/4068240):

> **4. And one more way using native means:**
>
> ```
> Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
> $zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead("e:\E.zip")
> $file = $zip.Entries | where-object { $_.Name -eq "XMLSchema1.xsd"}
> $stream = $file.Open()
>
> $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
> $text = $reader.ReadToEnd()
> $text
>
> $reader.Close()
> $stream.Close()
> $zip.Dispose()
> ```

`XMLSchema1.xsd` is where your file name would go.

The linked answer mentions some other ways (which are mostly linked to external dependencies and the Windows operating system). Most of them still extract at least one file, but to be precise:

Comment: @Clijsters Although it may not look perfect,it was the solution to my problem and to another one I had, so thank you and thanks to the author of the post you quoted!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but was the first to come up when I was looking to search for strings inside zipped log files. None of these answers worked for me because my log files were too large and I would get `Exception calling "ReadToEnd" with "0" argument(s): "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."` when it tried to do `$reader.ReadToEnd()`

So I rewrote it using `$reader.ReadLine()` to check the files a line at a time. This worked on multi-gig logs and was still pretty quick to return. I hope someone else finds this helpful:

```
function Search-ZippedLogs {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$ZipPattern,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$LogPattern,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$SearchPattern
    )
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

    # Usage Example: Search-ZippedLogs -Path "E:\application\log" -ZipPattern "all.log2023*.zip" -LogPattern "logfile*.log" -SearchPattern "*sent message*"

    if (-not $ZipPattern) {$ZipPattern="*.zip"}
    if (-not $LogPattern) {$LogPattern="*.log"}

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $ZipPattern | ForEach-Object {
        $zipFile = $_.FullName
        Write-Host "Searching $zipFile ..."
        $zipArchive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipFile)
        $zipArchive.Entries | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $LogPattern } | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "`tSearching $($_.Name)"
            $stream = $_.Open()
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)
            while ($line = $reader.ReadLine()) {
                if ($line -like $SearchPattern) {
                    Write-Host "`t$($_.Name): $line"
                }
            }
            $reader.Dispose()
            $stream.Dispose()
        }

        $zipArchive.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm working with zipped log files, there is only ever one file in the zip.

I made this function to grab the contents of the log file.

Credit to Andrey Marchuk and the 4th point of his answer in the link below.  His code is what I adapted to make this function.
[How to read contents of a csv file inside zip file using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561465/how-to-read-contents-of-a-csv-file-inside-zip-file-using-powershell)

```
function Get-ZippedLog {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$ZipPath
    )
    Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
    $zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead($ZipPath)

    $file = $zip.Entries[0]
    $stream = $file.Open()

    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
    $text = $reader.ReadToEnd()

    $reader.Close()
    $stream.Close()
    $zip.Dispose()

    return $text
}
```